# Parsing HTML issues with Apache Tika

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing, apache-tika

I am crawling a webpage and after crawling it extract all the links from that webpage and then I am trying to parse all the url using Apache Tika and BoilerPipe by using below code so for some url it is parsing very well but for some I get error like this. And it shows some error on HTMLParser.java: line number 102. This is line number 102 in HTMLParser.java

```
String parsedText = tika.parseToString(htmlStream, md);
```

I have provided the HTMLParse code also.

```
org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: TIKA-198: Illegal IOException from org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser@67c28a6a
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:203)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:135)
        at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:357)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:102)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.handleHtml(WebCrawler.java:227)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.processPage(WebCrawler.java:299)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.run(WebCrawler.java:118)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:114)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:55)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:82)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:220)
        at org.apache.poi.extractor.ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(ExtractorFactory.java:152)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLExtractorFactory.parse(OOXMLExtractorFactory.java:65)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser.parse(OOXMLParser.java:67)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
        ... 8 more
```

This is my HTMLParser.java file-

```
    public void parse(String htmlContent, String contextURL) {

        InputStream htmlStream = null;
        text = null;
        title = null;
        metaData = new HashMap<String, String>();

        urls = new HashSet<String>();
        char[] chars = htmlContent.toCharArray();

        bulletParser.setCallback(textExtractor);
        bulletParser.parse(chars);

        try {
            text = articleExtractor.getText(htmlContent);
        } catch (BoilerpipeProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (text == null){
            text = textExtractor.text.toString().trim(); 
        }

        title = textExtractor.title.toString().trim();
        try {
            Metadata md = new Metadata();
            String utfHtmlContent = new String(htmlContent.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
            htmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(utfHtmlContent.getBytes());
    //The below line is at the line number 102 according to error above
                String parsedText = tika.parseToString(htmlStream, md);
                //very unlikely to happen
                if (text == null){
                    text = parsedText.trim();
                }
                processMetaData(md);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(htmlStream);
            }
            bulletParser.setCallback(linkExtractor);
            bulletParser.parse(chars);
            Iterator<String> it = linkExtractor.urls.iterator();

            String baseURL = linkExtractor.base();
            if (baseURL != null) {
                contextURL = baseURL;
            }

            int urlCount = 0;
            while

 (it.hasNext()) {
            String href = it.next();
            href = href.trim();
            if (href.length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            String hrefWithoutProtocol = href.toLowerCase();
            if (href.startsWith("http://")) {
                hrefWithoutProtocol = href.substring(7);
            }
            if (hrefWithoutProtocol.indexOf("javascript:") < 0
                    && hrefWithoutProtocol.indexOf("@") < 0) {
                URL url = URLCanonicalizer.getCanonicalURL(href, contextURL);
                if (url != null) {
                    urls.add(url.toExternalForm());
                    urlCount++;
                    if (urlCount > MAX_OUT_LINKS) {
                        break;
                    }   
                }               
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but I think that you might be able to debug it easier if you either run through a debugger and examine htmlContent or at least log it. This might give you a clue as to whether there is something strange in the content.

Comment: Some problem with tika version?? as I am using Apache Tika 0.9 in the above case and that depends on poi3.7. So I am assuming there is some problem with org.apache.poi [http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.tika.user/543](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.tika.user/543)

Comment: And when I upgraded the tika version from 0.9 to 1.0 I started getting different error like this. `org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: TIKA-198: Illegal IOException from org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.PackageParser@4fd30479`

Comment: Are you sure the document isn't corrupt? If you download it to your machine, can you open it in Office / OpenOffice? (My hunch is that it won't open, and you'll get a similar error to the one Tika gave)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a malformed OOXML document (.docx, .xlsx, etc.). To check whether the problem still occurs with the latest Tika version, you can [download](http://tika.apache.org/download.html) the tika-app jar and run it like this:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.0.jar --text http://url.of.the/troublesome/document.docx
```

This should print out the text contained in the document. If it doesn't work, please file a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA) with the URL of the troublesome document (or attach the document if it's not publicly available).

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, I found that documents(docx) files which I was trying to parse was not actually simple document,  It was form developed in microsoft word with text and input fields beside label text.

I removed such files from folder and post rest of all files to Solr engine for parsing and indexing, It worked.

Comment: I found that the issue is with parsing "TotalTime" metadata of docx file.

metadata issue, following is error i got:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Error creating OOXML extractor
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLExtractorFactory.parse(OOXMLExtractorFactory.java:120)
at .
.
.
.
at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:145)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: Invalid int value: 4294966778